# jTable entering data into a column

Tags: java, sql, swing, for-loop, jtable

I have a jTable which I m using to enter student exam marks. When I enter marks into the "Marks" column it automatically check the Grade according to the entered marks and put it into the next column (which is "grade") ,same row. It works fine. When you have more than one row to enter marks there is a problem. We'll assume there are three student to enter marks, if you enter marks into the last row (student comes last in the table) the Grade will not updated. you have to come by order top to bottom to update Grade . Help me on this . Thanks. Here is my code :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
if(!(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString().equals(""))){
if(!(Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString())>100)){
        String mark = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 2).toString();
        int mk = Integer.parseInt(mark);
        if (mk >= 75) {
            jTable1.setValueAt("A", i, 3);
        } else if (mk < 75 && mk >= 65) {
            jTable1.setValueAt("B", i, 3);
        } else if (mk < 65 && mk >= 55) {
            jTable1.setValueAt("C", i, 3);
        } else if (mk < 55 && mk >= 35) {
            jTable1.setValueAt("S", i, 3);
        } else{
        jTable1.setValueAt("F", i, 3);
        }}}
```

Comment: I'd rather use a `CellRenderer` to show. And as a detail instead of doing two `if` you can use a `&&`

Comment: can u give me an example to use CellRenderer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a `CellRenderer` to achieve this. Something like this. You can extends `DefaultTableCellRenderer`  implementation

```
public class MarkCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable jTable, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(jTable, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (c instanceof JLabel) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) c;
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
            Integer mk = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());//this is not very clean
            String text= null;
            if (mk >= 75) {
               text="A";
            } else if (mk < 75 && mk >= 65) {
               text="B";
            } else if (mk < 65 && mk >= 55) {
               text="C";
            } else if (mk < 55 && mk >= 35) {
               text="S";
            } else{
                text="F";
            }
            label.setText(text);
    }
        return c;
    }
}
```

And you set like

```
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(new MarkCellRenderer());
```

Comment: @ShanakaPerera remember swing components implements MVC pattern, so you have to separate what is view from model. you can have in your table model a number but showing in view a letter. :D Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it's useful :)

Comment: @nachokk: Shanaka Perera cannot vote up with < 15 reputation.

Comment: @trashgod oh i see :( :D